# Access Is Denied error pushing package into my azure devops artifacts nuget feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-cli, nuget-credential-provider

In [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772765/how-do-i-set-up-azure-dev-ops-to-build-dev-express-xaf-xpo-project) I managed to push one package to my feed, however I now get an Access is denied error.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511512/authenticating-to-vsts-package-management?rq=1) I should be prompted for user name and password.  This did occur for the package I managed to push, but it no longer occurs.

What do I need to do?

Studying the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

[this issue on Git is relevant](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/757)

[Update]

Something strange has happened to my folder.
I get the error if I just type Nuget at the dos prompt.
If I create a new folder and extract nugetcredentialprovider.zip into it, then run Nuget I don't get the error

[the cli reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)

[push reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push)

[configuring nuget behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363124/vsts-nuget-package-feed-authentication?rq=1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/extensibility/nuget-exe-credential-providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting over again with a new installation of credentialsprovider solved the problem.

I accidentally cause the problem again by pasting in a command that started with the directory name

(a cut and paste boo booo)

[image: access is denied]